# I am getting timeout error while installing meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am not able to install meteor.js. I am getting execution timeout. How can I install meteor.js

See screenshot (error) :

[image]

Comment: read the pink sentence

Comment: @Naramsim I couldn't get what does that mean ?

Comment: @Naramsim Do I need to do all that stuff in CMD or powershell because I have used CMD.

Comment: @Naramsim Should I use `--execution-timeout=myvalue` or `choco --execution-timeout=myvalue`

Comment: I would say `choco --...`, I dont know if the flag goes before or after the package that you need to install. Just `choco -h` to discover it

Comment: How it went? @stone rock

Comment: @Naramsim I have downloaded meteor.js setup file and now it works on my windows machine. I have not installed it using `choco`.